# Equality of sets

Tags: prolog

Can anyone help me with the following task: I need to define a predicate eq_set, which succeeds if the sets `S1` and `S2` are equal when it comes to the number of their elements.

But it works only if they are exactly the same number and order. I want to create a code that shows all varieties and doesn't take order into account. Can you help me,please?

I wrote:

```
eq_set([],[]).
eq_set([H|T],[H|T1]) :-
    eq_set(T,T1).
```

But it works only if they are exactly the same number and order. I want to create a code that shows all varieties and doesn't take order into account.

**The closest translation I have of the assignment, which is in Bulgarian, is: "Define the predicate eq_set, which succeeds if the sets (S1, S2) coincide.**

Comment: Thanks , that fixes one part of the problem. When I made that correction it says that [1,2,3] is equal to [4,5,6], which means that it takes into account only the length. I've been advised to use the predicates 'member' and 'subset' to try to define that the elements of S1 should be the elements in S2. It means that, for example, [1,2,3] should be considered equal to [3,2,1], which it does now, but it should somehow be able to compare the elements... I'd be extremely thankful if you help me and I'm sorry for being obviously a bit dull.

Comment: Two sets coincide when they have the exact same elements in them, is that right? Just making it clear. And the sets are represented as unordered lists without duplicates? (not absolutely certain, this is kinda important). Must at least one of the two arguments be ground? Nonvar? Please give examples of querying the predicate on the toplevel.

Comment: Can you give the Bulgarian version of the assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You call them "sets" but the data structure you are using is a list. It is easiest to just sort the two lists:

```
eq_set(A, B) :-
    % prerequisites: A and B are lists without duplicates
    sort(A, S),
    sort(B, S).
```

If you want something more complicated (for some reason) you need to be more specific.

With this definition:

```
?- eq_set([a,b,c], [a,b]).
false. % OK

?- eq_set([a,b,c], [a,b,c]).
true. % OK

?- eq_set([a,c,b], [a,b,c]).
true. % OK

?- eq_set([a,a,b], [a,b,b]).
true. % Not sure....
```

Comment: They told me that they shouldn't be lists. It's an assignment and it should be pretty simple but it's difficult for me, because I'm a linguist and my terminology might not be the best. I was advised to use the predicate "member" and/or "subset" and I think it should be able to give me the other possible options ([1,2,3], [3,2,1], [2,3,1] and so on. I haven't prepared a data base and I don't think I should. It has to work in the dialogue.

Comment: @PressyLazarova You really need to describe in enough detail your assignment and the context. Who are "They"? `[1, 2, 3]` _is a list_ so why are "they" telling you such stuff? If you are a linguist you must know how to work with terminology (I know linguists personally, they are not "obviously a bit dull").

Comment: @PressyLazarova The path of least resistance would be to copy-paste the assignment _exactly as it is worded_ so that nothing is lost in translation (you can edit your question and add it there). Then, we at least know what is _expected of you_ which is of course more important than anything else when it comes to school (which is why school is bad for your health... but I got distracted).

Comment: Well, it's quite tough for me to describe it in detail and in the right English terminology, because the task is given to me in Bulgarian. "They" are the teachers that gave me the assignment and who advised me to use the "member" predicate. I will do my best to translate the task: "Define the predicate eq_set, which succeeds if the sets (S1, S2) coincide. I know other type of terminology and this is the first time I encounter any type of programming, so don't be so critical :)

Comment: @PressyLazarova OK, getting closer. Two more questions: a) _how do you represent_ a "set"? (It seems it is a _Prolog list_ without duplicates, but not in any particular order, and I'd guess that "coincide" means that if you did sort the elements then the two lists would be the same?); and b) how are you supposed to use the predicate? The second question is probably the difficult one to answer without a bit more context. At least give a couple of examples. Like, is this how it should work: `?- eq_set([a,b] S). S = [a, b] ; S = [b,a].`

Comment: @PressyLazarova The problem is the following: if you have a predicate that _tests_ if two lists without duplicates have the same set of elements in them, then just sorting as I showed is the best way to do it. But if you want to do it so that it is a general relation that just holds true, then we need to get down to details like "how do you represent a set", "when do two sets in this representation coincide", "can the arguments to the predicate be non-ground or even free variables", and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

It really *really* depends on how the predicate is going to be used.

Assuming that a "set" is indeed a Prolog list without duplicates but not in any particular order; then two sets in that presentation "coincide" if they are permutations of each other. In other words, it would be enough to define `eq_set/2` as:

```
eq_set(A, B) :-
    my_permutation(A, B).
```

and just use the textbook definition of `permutation/2` which uses the textbook definition of `select/3` (See "The Art of Prolog (Second Edition)" by Sterling and Shapiro, pp 67-9):

```
my_permutation([], []).
my_permutation(Xs, [Y|Ys]) :-
    my_select(Y, Xs, Xs0),
    my_permutation(Xs0, Ys).

my_select(X, [X|Xs], Xs).
my_select(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]) :-
    my_select(X, Ys, Zs).
```

(I renamed those just to make sure I am not using the standard library definitions; SWI-Prolog has both [`select/3`](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/b0168ea4a94d95da8769df94ec627eb54047dac1/library/lists.pl#L153-L164) and [`permutation/2`](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/b0168ea4a94d95da8769df94ec627eb54047dac1/library/lists.pl#L410-L463) in the [autoloaded library(lists)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists); the definitions are basically the same, but they do some run-time type-checking on the arguments.)

Here is how you can use it:

```
?- eq_set([1,2,3], [2,3,1]).
true ;
false.

?- eq_set([1,2,3], S).
S = [1, 2, 3] ;
S = [1, 3, 2] ;
S = [2, 1, 3] ;
S = [2, 3, 1] ;
S = [3, 1, 2] ;
S = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.

?- eq_set([1,2,3], [1,2]).
false.

?- eq_set(A, B).
A = B, B = [] ;
A = B, B = [_4480] ;
A = B, B = [_4480, _4492] ;
...
```

I am not sure how useful the last query is. You can force it to enumerate solutions in order of increasing size of the "set", like this:

```
?- length(S1, _), eq_set(S1, S2), numbervars(S1).
S1 = S2, S2 = [] ;
S1 = S2, S2 = [A] ;
S1 = S2, S2 = [A, B] ;
S1 = [A, B],
S2 = [B, A] ;
S1 = S2, S2 = [A, B, C] ;
S1 = [A, B, C],
S2 = [A, C, B] ;
S1 = [A, B, C],
S2 = [B, A, C] ;
S1 = [A, B, C],
S2 = [B, C, A] ;
S1 = [A, B, C],
S2 = [C, A, B] ;
S1 = [A, B, C],
S2 = [C, B, A] ;
S1 = S2, S2 = [A, B, C, D] .
```

(Don't worry about the `numbervars`, it is just there to give readable names to all the free variables in the sets. Keep in mind that unifying two free variables makes them the same variable.)

This is a starting point, but maybe it is already good enough. The most glaring omission is that it doesn't require the arguments to be lists without duplicates. One way to define this would be to require that each element is different from all other elements. Since "is different" is commutative, you can define it like this:

```
is_set([]).
is_set([X|Xs]) :-
    all_different(Xs, X),
    is_set(Xs).

all_different([], _).
all_different([Y|Ys], X) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    all_different(Ys, X).
```

This uses `dif/2` which is a widely available predicate (but does your Prolog have it?).

We would have maybe used `maplist` for that last one:

```
is_set([]).
is_set([X|Xs]) :-
    maplist(dif(X), Xs).
    is_set(Xs).
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close in your solution.

We have two cases
1) The first list argument is bigger
2) The second list argument is bigger

If you already know which one is bigger, you can just do

```
%in case the left one is longer
eq_set_left(_,[]).
eq_set_left(X,[H|T]):-member(H,X), eq_set_left(X,T).
```

So a very simple solution and yet very optimal could be this:

```
%in case the right one is longer
eq_set_right([],_).
eq_set_right([H|T], X):- member(H,X), eq_set_right(T,X).

%in case the left one is longer
eq_set_left(_,[]).
eq_set_left(X,[H|T]):-member(H,X), eq_set_left(X,T).

%both cases, equal length is also included here
eq_set(X,Y):- eq_set_left(X,Y).
eq_set(X,Y):- eq_set_right(X,Y).
```

eq_set(X, Y) is true if either X is subset of Y, Y is subset of X or they are equal

Comment: This only says "false" no matter what: `?- eq_set([1], [1]).
false.

?- eq_set_left([1], [1]).
false.

?- eq_set_right([1], [1]).
false.
`. I think you have used `member/2` incorrectly. Downvoting until you fix at least that, sorry.

Comment: Yes thank you. The arguments for the member predicate were swapped

Comment: But how did you come up with the actual semantics? Like, now, it says, "eq_set(X, Y) is true if either X is subset of Y, Y is subset of X or they are equal". How does that relate to "the two sets coincide" from the original question? I am asking because exactly this is the missing information that I couldn't squeeze out of OP.

Comment: There are other small problems with your solution, but first I'd like to understand the question.

Comment: My understanding of the question is:
We have two sets A and B.
eq_set should be true if all elements of A are contained in B or if all elements of B are contained in A

Comment: Is that the meaning of "two sets coincide"?

Comment: In more conventional use, "two sets coincide" when the two sets have the same elements, that is, the two sets are actually equal. (Removed the downvote, because the code does what it claims. Not sure if it answers the question).

Answer (score 0):

A *set* is defined as a collection of *distinct* things where order is not important, which is to say that sets `{a,b,c}` and `{b,a,c}` are identical.

From that, one could say that two sets are identical if neither set contains an element that is not also found in the other (or conversely, two sets are not identical if either set contains an element not found in the other.

From that, one could simply say:

```
eq_set(Xs,Ys) :-
   findall( (Xs,Ys) , ( member(X,Xs), \+ member(X,Ys) ), [] ),
   findall( (Xs,Ys) , ( member(Y,Ys), \+ member(Y,Xs) ), [] )
   .
```

Or if you don't want to use the built-in `findall/3`,

```
eq_set(Xs,Ys) :-
  a_not_in_b( Xs , Ys , [] ) ,
  a_not_in_b( Ys , Xs , [] ) .

a_not_in_b( []     , [] , [] ) .
a_not_in_b( [A|As] , Bs , Xs ) :- member(A,Bs) , a_not_in_b( As, Bs,    Xs  ) .
a_not_in_b( [A|As] , Bs , Xs ) :-                a_not_in_b( As, Bs, [A|Xs] ) .
```

One should note that both of these has roughly O(N<sup>2</sup>) performance. If the sets in question are large, you might want to first sort each set and then merge the two sorted lists to identify those elements that are not common to both sets:

```
eq_set(Xs,Ys) :-
  sort(Xs,X1),
  sort(Ys,Y1),
  X1 == Y1.
```

Comment: The question is not completely clear on that, but it seems that the query `?- eq_set([a, b], S).` should answer `S = [a, b] ; S = [b, a]`. In your answer, solution 1 and 2 don't terminate and solution 3 throws an instantiation error. Solution 3 is also just an unnecessarily verbose version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719477/10721357). If I didn't know better, I'd almost say you didn't read the question or the existing answers :-(

Comment: PS: the second argument of `sort/2` is a finite list. For two such lists, `A == B` and `A = B` are only diffent if the lists have free variables, and I am struggling to figure out a use for not unifying those in the context of `eq_set/2`.